# Выбор шаблона проектирования

Tags: php, ооп

Подскажите, как как грамотно сделать.

Есть класс `Goods`, который описывает работу с 1 товаром. Получая в конструкторе `Id` товара, он находит его в базе, и дальше он умеет производить все необходимые операции с 1 единицой товара.
По задаче мне надо вывести 10 товаров в зависимости от выбранных фильтров.
Мне надо уже использовать другой класс (я так понимаю что его правильно назвать `GoodsCollection`), который в базе ищет список `Id` товаров.

Далее надо с найденым результатом как то работать.
Тут я вижу 3 варианта:

1. `GoodsCollection` возвращает массив объектов `Goods`
2. `GoodsCollection` возвращает массив `Id`, в цикле сначала создаются, потом разрушаются объекты `Goods`
3. Перед началом цикла создается объект `Goods`, а далее в цикле сначала выбирается `Id`, находится в базе товар, и в конце делается flush данных.

Какой вариант более правильный?
1 объект памяти занимает не много, и его инициализация происходит быстро.

Answer (score 1):

Шаблоны это же рекомендации по написанию уже с предусмотренными вариантами развития приложения. Улучшайте их дописывайте своё. Вот пример пула фабрики который у меня лежит на рабочем столе где-то нашел уже давно и сохранил:

```
class Factory
    {

        /**
         * @var Product[]
         */
        protected static $products = array();


        /**
         * Добавляет продукт в пул
         *
         * @param Product $product
         * @return void
         */
        public static function pushProduct(Product $product)
        {
            self::$products[$product->getId()] = $product;
        }

        /**
         * Возвращает продукт из пула
         *
         * @param integer|string $id - идентификатор продукта
         * @return Product $product
         */
        public static function getProduct($id)
        {
            return isset(self::$products[$id]) ? self::$products[$id] : null;
        }

        /**
         * Удаляет продукт из пула
         *
         * @param integer|string $id - идентификатор продукта
         * @return void
         */
        public static function removeProduct($id)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($id, self::$products)) {
                unset(self::$products[$id]);
            }
        }
    }

    class Product
    {

        /**
         * @var integer|string
         */
        protected $id;


        public function __construct($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
        }

        /**
         * @return integer|string
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    }

    /*
     * =====================================
     *         USING OF OBJECT POOL
     * =====================================
     */

    Factory::pushProduct(new Product('first'));
    Factory::pushProduct(new Product('second'));

    print_r(Factory::getProduct('first')->getId());
    // first
    print_r(Factory::getProduct('second')->getId());
    // second
```

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер!
Если я правильно понял, то в Вашей реализации при создании объекта класса Goods инициируется обращение к базе данных для получения данных, которыми будет инициализирован объект.
При таком подходе при создании коллекций объектов, Вы столкнетесь с проблемой (n+1) запросов, где n - количество найденных идентификаторов, а 1 - это первый запрос, который ищет идентификаторы объектов, которые удовлетворяют условиям фильтрации. Очевидно, что такое количество запросов избыточно и все необходимые данные можно собрать за один запрос.
Более правильном было бы выделить отдельный класс GoodsFinder, обязанностью которого было бы нахождение соответствующих записей в базе данных.

```
$finder = new GoodsFinder();
$goods = $finder->find($id);
```

Метод find должен возвращать инициализированный экземпляр класса Goods.
В таком случае, Вам необходимо переписать конструктор класса Goods таким образом, чтобы он принимал в качестве входного параметра данные полученные из базы и передавал их значения своим внутренним свойствам.
Таким образом Вы вынесите код взаимодействия с базой данных в отдельный класс, а ваша бизнес-модель будет отвечать только за соблюдения бизнес-правил, вы получите более четкое разделение ответственности и код в дальнейшем будет легче поддерживать. Плюс, такой код легче покрыть юнит-тестами.
Таким образом получении коллекции объектов будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$collection = $finder->findBy($filters);

Class GoodsCollection {

    private $objects = [];

    public function __construct($data) {
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $this->objects[] = new Goods($row);
        }
    }

    // ... методы для получения объектов из коллекции

}
```

Есть, конечно, вариант оставить код для взаимодействия с базой данных в классе Goods, переопределив конструктор:

```
Class Goods
{
    // Если передаем массив, инициализируем свойства класса, если нет, допускаем, что на вход пришел идентификатор и ищем данные в базе
    public function __construct($initData) {
        if (is_array($initData) {
            $this->setProperties($initData);
        } else {
            $this->find($initData);
        }
    }

}
```

К такому методу можно прибегнуть, если слишком многие компоненты системы рассчитывают на условия контракта конструктора. Хотя я бы советовал не лениться и провести рефакторинг кода с разделением обязанностей.
Это общие рекомендации. Советую также почитать про паттерны объектно-реляционного отображения, такие как: ActiveRecord, TableGateway и DataMapper. Также не стоит забывать, что уже есть готовые решения (например, в Yii - ActiveRecord, Doctrine - хороший пример комплексного применения паттернов объектно-реляционного отображения), возможно еще не поздно внедрить их в Ваш проект. 
В любом случае, заглянуть в репозитории готовых решений будет отличной идеей для того, чтобы посмотреть, как это реализовано у них.